# sscanf in MASM assembly language

Tags: masm, ieee-754

Why this piece of code doesn`t work on my Windows 10-11 machines, but works just fine in Windows 7. sscanf return 0 (error I guess)

```
.code
main proc
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 30h
    mov rcx, offset buffer
    mov rdx, offset fmt1
    mov r8, offset temp
    invoke sscanf
    movq xmm0, temp
    ret
main endp

.data
fmt1 db "%lf", 0
temp dq ?
buffer db "3.14159264", 0
end
```

And this code works just fine, BUT when I use same piece of code in another project it just does not work, something make it unworkable, why?
This piece of code:

```
wmCOMMAND:

cmp r8d, BN_CLICKED shl 16 + ID_BIN
    je   wmCONV_BIN
cmp r8d, BN_CLICKED shl 16 + ID_DEC
    je  wmCONV_DEC
cmp r8d, BN_CLICKED shl 16 + ID_CLEAR
    je  wmCLEAR
cmp r8d,BN_CLICKED shl 16 + IDCANCEL
    jne     wmBYE

wmCONV_BIN:
; check if no zero
lea r8, buffer
invoke  GetDlgItemTextA,,ID_TXT1,,size_of_buffer;255  ID_TXT1 = Decimal representation
or      eax,eax
jz      wmBYE

mov rcx, offset buffer
mov rdx, offset fmt1
mov r8, offset temp
invoke  sscanf   ; RETURN 0

movq    xmm0, temp
cvtsd2ss xmm0,xmm0
movd    value,xmm0

;------some code
.data
buffer db 255 dup (?)
szWin   db 'WM_COPYDATA Reciever',0
fmt db "%08Xh",0
fmt0    db "%d",0
fmt1    db "%lf", 0
fmt2    db "%lf (denormalized)",0
fmt3    db "%.16lf",0
value   dd ?
temp    dq ?
sign0   db "+1",0
sign1   db "-1",0
sign    dq sign0,sign1
sign2   db "0",0
Exponent dd ?
Mantissa dd ?
const8388608 dq 8388608.0;2^23=8388608
const1  dq 1.0
denorm  db "-126 (denormalized)",0
```

Since 64-bit MASM by Microsoft no longer has an invoke directive I am using a Russian [MASM64 SDK](http://dsmhelp.narod.ru/environment.htm#id_newmacros) project that has an invoke macro.

UPDATE:
It might sound stupid, but after running the code provided in the first example for about 5 minutes, it stopped working. Now, even sscanf there returns 0.

Comment: Why are you using `invoke` instead of the `call` instruction? With `invoke`, you are supposed to put the arguments on the `invoke` line, and it generates instructions to pass them according to whatever calling convention has been set, followed by a `call` instruction. If you give it no arguments, it may set something indicating there are no arguments, depending on the calling convention. If you are passing the arguments yourself, you should just use a `call` instruction. If you want to use `invoke`, put the arguments on the `invoke` line.

Comment: Invoke do some checking for stack aligment etc, so it's no point to use call for me.

Comment: If you want to use `invoke`, put the arguments on the `invoke` line.

Comment: In the first code snippet, how does the `ret` work without having balanced the stack after `push rbp` and `sub rsp, 30h` ?

Comment: @SepRoland MASM puts `leave` to do this